# How to get the object owner through object_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models in this situation: User and Answer. User has_many answers and Answer belongs_to user. How do I get the User object through the user_id attribute of the answer object? I mean, is there an easy way to do it like "answer.user" ? I don't want to use something like User.find(answer.user_id) and the reason is that I can't make requests on the client side. See the code below:

```
  <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="row answer">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p><%= search_long_words(answer.text) %></p>
        <p>respondido por <%= link_to "#{answer.user.username}", profile_path(answer.user_id) %> em <%= answer.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <% if user_signed_in? && answer.user_id == current_user.id %>
          <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_answer_path(answer) %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <% if user_signed_in? && answer.user_id == current_user.id %>
          <%= link_to 'Apagar', answer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Deseja apagar sua resposta?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: i don't understand what's the problem, the `answer.user` should work by default if you have your associations correctly

Comment: did you define associations in your models?

Comment: Guys, I'm feeling really silly here :(
The belongs_to wasn't in the model though I was sure I had put :(
Sorry for disturbing and thanks for your help! I will mark your answers if post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is pretty silly but I feel I need to post the answer due to community responsibility.
The problem was that I had forgotten to define the association in my model, so I put the 'belongs_to' in the answer and it worked, as stated by the guys above.